# Is it possible to have an app block other apps even if you restart device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Is it possible to have an app block other apps even if you restart the device?

Comment: If your entire question fits in the title, it's not enough detail. What do you mean by "block"?

Comment: If it interferes with other apps, it might require root permission

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say can there be an app that forces you to do a certain function (like a puzzle game) before you can get out of it and use the rest of the device?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52899814/edit) your question to explain in detail what/why do you want to do this and who is the owner of the device (business or individual).

Comment: On iOS it isn't possible to have an app block another app period

Answer (score 0):

Android provides the ability to draw over other apps (Tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9)). In combination with an accessibility service, you should be able to detect when a user attempts to interact with a particular application and draw over that app.

The user needs to enable the permission though, so you can't really "block" the app permanently.

Source: I wrote an application that uses an accessibility service to detect Japanese Kanji in tapped areas in other apps. The app then uses the "draw over other apps" permission to show an info panel about the parsed Kanji.